# How to fix Auto Vertical Scrollbar space in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, scroll, scrollbar

Very simple scenario But I have wasted lots of time, so I am asking here. I have a wpf application. 
A listview is there with vertical scrollbar visibility to Auto and horizontal scrollbar visibility disabled. Now when I start adding item in it, like there is 2 items and no vertical scrollbar is there because of Auto. Now as I add 3rd item, a vertical scrollbar gets visible and content shifted towards left with some 15 pixel. 
It looks weird and I want that content remains in the same position and only scrollbar get visible or collapsed. 
I have tried setting margin to inner item or padding to listview. But nothing works.

Comment: Set `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`

Comment: @AnandMurali I cannot show horizontal scroll bar, it is disabled.

Comment: I am sorry I meant to say set VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Visible

Comment: @AnandMurali But I cannot set it visible all the time, it looks weird. It should visible only when it is required without any content displacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following: Add a scrollviewer control to your GUI, right click -> edit a template -> edit a copy

Now here´s the thing your looking for:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerControlTemplateOwn" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The *auto* setting for the column and row definitions are causing the change in the width when scrollbars are visible or not.
If you change those *auto* values to e.g. 20 the display won´t change in width or height.
For adding such a scrollviewer to a listview, do the same "edit a copy" thing with the listview and set the scrollviewer to your "own" template like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Style="{Binding ScrollViewerControlTemplateOwn}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
```

Hope that helps :)